# How to disable auto correction for Google Cloud Speech to Text API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, speech-to-text, google-speech-api, google-cloud-speech

Is there a way to disable auto correction for Google Cloud Speech to Text API? It is important for me to get accurate transcript of user's speech, with any errors they make rather than a corrected version.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to distinguish between mistakes made by speaker (grammar/pronunciation errors) in the audio content and mistakes made by Speech API. However, you can check different versions of text output predicted by model behind the scene with the help of **maxAlternatives** property of the API.

You have not provided the example of such use-case, but if you are already expecting unusual pronunciation or Acronyms you can provide hint to the request using **phraseHint** property.

Please provide further details if it doesn't answer your question.